# How do I confirm static byte weaving happened?

Tags: eclipselink

I added maven-antrun-plugin and I see a bunch of lines (see below) but I can I tell if the byte-weaving actually occurred?  Seems like black magic to me :-).  There doesn't appear to be anything different in the eclipselink log file when I run.

[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (default) @ austin-dbaccess ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [java] [EL Config]: metadata: 2013-12-05 16:03:53.182--ServerSession(1858215506)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class com.sss.dbaccess.TriggerJson] is set to [PROPERTY].

Answer (score 0):

In persistence.xml add  to your list of properties. In the log you should then see information about the weaving.